# Python Pandas aggregate past rows when a condition is met for time series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series problem and I want to aggregate some data based on the values that appear in a certain column. to illustrate, consider the following table

| Date | colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | 1 | -10 | Null |
| 2019-01-02 | 2 | -5 | Null |
| 2019-01-03 | 3 | 0 | 101 |
| 2019-01-04 | 4 | 5 | 101 |
| 2019-01-05 | 5 | 10 | 101 |
| 2019-01-06 | 6 | 15 | Null |
| 2019-01-07 | 7 | 20 | 101 |

I want to accomplish the following:

1. the moment the value of colC is not null, aggregate the values up to that row and get the delta for the date column
2. if the element X of colC is not null but the element (X-1) is also not null, just disregard row X.

For the previous table, the result would be

| agg(colC) | avg(colA) | avg(colB) | delta(Date) [in days] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2 | -5 | 2 |
| 101 | 6.5 | 17.5 | 1 |

I could not find any way to accomplish that so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set groups of `colC` with [`cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), and then group by the groups by [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html), as follows:

(Assuming the Null values are `NaN` or None):

```
# Convert date to datetime format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# disregard rows if the element X of colC is not null but the element (X-1) is also not null
df2 = df.loc[df['colC'].isna() | df['colC'].shift().isna()]

# set grouping for `colC`
group = (df2['colC'].shift(1).notna() & df2['colC'].isna()).cumsum()

df_out = (df2.groupby(group, as_index=False)
             .agg(**{'agg(colC)':('colC', 'last'), 
                     'avg(colA)':('colA', 'mean'),
                     'avg(colB)':('colB', 'mean'), 
                     'delta(Date)':('Date', lambda x: (x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0]).days)})
         )
```

**Data Input:**

```
data = {'Date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-07'],
 'colA': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 'colB': [-10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20],
 'colC': [np.nan, np.nan, 101.0, 101.0, 101.0, np.nan, 101.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

         Date  colA  colB   colC
0  2019-01-01     1   -10    NaN
1  2019-01-02     2    -5    NaN
2  2019-01-03     3     0  101.0
3  2019-01-04     4     5  101.0
4  2019-01-05     5    10  101.0
5  2019-01-06     6    15    NaN
6  2019-01-07     7    20  101.0
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

   agg(colC)  avg(colA)  avg(colB)  delta(Date)
0      101.0        2.0       -5.0            2
1      101.0        6.5       17.5            1
```

#### Explanation / Illustration

Let's add more data for better illustration:

```
data = {'Date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-08', '2019-01-09', '2019-01-10', '2019-01-11', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-13', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-15'],
 'colA': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 
 'colB': [-10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20],
 'colC': [np.nan, np.nan, 101, 101, 101, np.nan, np.nan, 102, 103, 104, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 112, 113]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


          Date  colA  colB   colC
0   2019-01-01     1   -10    NaN
1   2019-01-02     2    -5    NaN
2   2019-01-03     3     0  101.0
3   2019-01-04     4     5  101.0
4   2019-01-05     5    10  101.0
5   2019-01-06     6    15    NaN
6   2019-01-07     7    15    NaN
7   2019-01-08     8    15  102.0
8   2019-01-09     9    20  103.0
9   2019-01-10    10    20  104.0
10  2019-01-11    11    15    NaN
11  2019-01-12    12    15    NaN
12  2019-01-13    13    15    NaN
13  2019-01-14    14    20  112.0
14  2019-01-15    15    20  113.0
```

After date format conversion, we discard unwanted rows by keeping only rows that are either with `NaN` on `colC` or even when current row is not `NaN` but its previous row is `NaN` on `colC`.

```
# Convert date to datetime format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df2 = df.loc[df['colC'].isna() | df['colC'].shift().isna()]
```

**Result:**

```
print(df2)

         Date  colA  colB   colC
0  2019-01-01     1   -10    NaN
1  2019-01-02     2    -5    NaN
2  2019-01-03     3     0  101.0
5  2019-01-06     6    15    NaN
6  2019-01-07     7    15    NaN
7  2019-01-08     8    15  102.0
10 2019-01-11    11    15    NaN
11 2019-01-12    12    15    NaN
12 2019-01-13    13    15    NaN
13 2019-01-14    14    20  112.0
```

Now, for setting groups, for illustration purpose, let's show the intermediate column values also in the dataframe by making intermediate columns:

```
df2['Group_indicator'] = df2['colC'].shift(1).notna() & df2['colC'].isna()
```

We set boolean mask so that the first entry of a group is set to `True` and the other entries `False` (there's exception on first row, but no problem when we generate the serial numbers for the groups)

**Result:**

```
         Date  colA  colB   colC  Group_indicator
0  2019-01-01     1   -10    NaN            False
1  2019-01-02     2    -5    NaN            False
2  2019-01-03     3     0  101.0            False
5  2019-01-06     6    15    NaN             True
6  2019-01-07     7    15    NaN            False
7  2019-01-08     8    15  102.0            False
10 2019-01-11    11    15    NaN             True
11 2019-01-12    12    15    NaN            False
12 2019-01-13    13    15    NaN            False
13 2019-01-14    14    20  112.0            False
```

Then, we generate the group numbers:

```
df2['Group'] = df2['Group_indicator'].cumsum()
```

**Result:**

```
         Date  colA  colB   colC  Group_indicator  Group
0  2019-01-01     1   -10    NaN            False      0
1  2019-01-02     2    -5    NaN            False      0
2  2019-01-03     3     0  101.0            False      0
5  2019-01-06     6    15    NaN             True      1
6  2019-01-07     7    15    NaN            False      1
7  2019-01-08     8    15  102.0            False      1
10 2019-01-11    11    15    NaN             True      2
11 2019-01-12    12    15    NaN            False      2
12 2019-01-13    13    15    NaN            False      2
13 2019-01-14    14    20  112.0            False      2
```

You can see that the serial numbers of groups are generated for each group with same group numbers for all entries of the same group.

After that, we group with this group number and aggregate the rows with  the code:

```
df_out = (df2.groupby('Group', as_index=False)
             .agg(**{'agg(colC)':('colC', 'last'), 
                     'avg(colA)':('colA', 'mean'),
                     'avg(colB)':('colB', 'mean'), 
                     'delta(Date)':('Date', lambda x: (x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0]).days)})
         )
```

Here, as our interested entry of `colC` is the **last** entry within a group, we aggregate with `'last'` on `colC`.

For the aggregation on `Date` to get `delta(Date)`, we take the last/first entry of `Date` with the group by `x.iloc[-1]` /  `x.iloc[0]` (i.e. the last and first entries of the Pandas Series for `Date` within a group) and calculate their difference by subtraction.  As this is a time series, the last/first entries should correspond to the max/min entries of `Date` within the group.

Hence, the result:

```
   Group  agg(colC)  avg(colA)  avg(colB)  delta(Date)
0      0      101.0        2.0      -5.00            2
1      1      102.0        7.0      15.00            2
2      2      112.0       12.5      16.25            3
```

Here, the result has a column `Group` while our original code version without it. This is because we defined a separate Pandas series `group` for the grouping, rather than defining a helper column `Group` in this illustration.

Answer (score 5):

Try with `groupby`:

```
#convert Date column to datetime if needed
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

#keep only rows where there aren't consecutive non-null values
df2 = df[~(df["colC"].notnull()&df["colC"].shift().notnull())]

#groupby consecutive null values and aggregate
output = df2.groupby(df2["colC"].notnull().shift().cumsum().fillna(0)) \
            .agg({"colA": "mean", \
                  "colB": "mean", \
                  "colC": "first", \
                  "Date": lambda x: (x.max()-x.min()).days}) \
            .rename_axis(None) \
            .rename(columns={"Date": "Delta"})

>>> output
     colA  colB   colC  Delta
0.0   2.0  -5.0  101.0      2
1.0   6.5  17.5  101.0      1
```